# Как сгенерировать случайное число с определенным количеством знаков после запятой?

Tags: javascript

Как можно написать на классическом JS функцию, которая бы выдавала случайное число (со знаками после запятой)? При этом через параметр функции я хочу указать, сколько знаков после запятой должно быть в этом числе.

Comment: `console.log( Number( Math.random().toFixed(5) ) )`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а зачем тут `Number`?Я проверил вроде как и без него работает.

Comment: @Demon__: потому, что `toFixed()` возвращает строку, а в вопросе просили число.

Comment: @UModeL ясно спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandom(number = 0, fixed = 1) {
    return Number(number)+Number(Math.random().toFixed(fixed));
}
```

Пример использования:

```js
getRandom(Math.random(), 3) // случайное число с 3 случайными знаками после запятой
getRandom(4) // 4.x
```